# Posting File Input as FileReader Binary Data through AJAX Post

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, filereader

I am trying to post an attachment uploaded to an HTML file input to a web page through a rest API. The API documentation states that the post is a straight binary content as the body of the HTTP request, not a form file upload.

My code is as follows:

```
$('#_testButton').bind('click', function () {
    var file = document.getElementById('_testFile').files[0]
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/attachmentURL',
            type: 'POST',
            data: reader.result
        })
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
})
```

I need this to work for a number of different mimeTypes, so I didn't declare it in the code above. However, I have tried declaring contentType:'application/msword' for a .doc file and also tried processData:false and contentType:false.

The data is being posted where it should. However, when I open the file, I get a message that says mimeType:application/x-empty with an empty file OR a file with a bunch of binary characters. I've tried .doc files and a pdf files and the result is the same for both.

Does anyone have a clue what I can change to make this work?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Simply sending the `file` reference as data (with `processData: false`) did the job for me at least:

```
$('#_testButton').bind('click', function () {
    var file = document.getElementById('_testFile').files[0];

    $.ajax({
        url: "/attachmentURL",
        type: "POST",
        data: file,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

It is described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#section_3

Sending a string (even if that string represents binary data) will not work because the browser will forcibly turn it into unicode and encode as utf-8 as [specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method) which will corrupt the binary data:

> If data is a string Let encoding be UTF-8.
>
> Let mime type be "text/plain;charset=UTF-8".
>
> Let the request entity body be data converted to Unicode and encoded
>   as UTF-8.

Sending a `file` reference (`blob`) will do this:

> If data is a Blob If the object's type attribute is not the empty
>   string let mime type be its value.
>
> Let the request entity body be the raw data represented by data.

Comment: -1: OP says, the server wants a direct binary content, not a content enveloped in a form data.

Comment: @EricH. I will hack around a bit and come up with a solution. I simply misunderstood your intentions.

Comment: Esailija: Haha, looks like you use SO as your social network!
@EricH. The way you are doing it, looks fine to me; unless server is looking for something else..

Comment: @Thrustmaster it should now send the binary data directly as POST data. Tested it too. :P

Comment: @Esailija -1 Withdrawn, and +1. :)

Comment: Bah Bammm!  That worked once I explicitly declared the MIME type.  That's easy with `contentType:file.type`.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @EricH. That's strange, according to specification it should be read automatically from the file: *If the object's `type` attribute is not the empty string let mime type be its value.* Oh well, whatever works :)

Comment: For me, it has worked well only when I've set the `contentType: false` or `contentType: file.type`.

Answer (score 1):

var file;

```
        $('#_testFile').on("change", function (e) {
            file = e.target.files[0];
        });
        $('#_testButton').click(function () {
            var serverUrl = '/attachmentURL';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);
                },
                url: serverUrl,
                data: file,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("File available at: ", data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    alert(obj.error);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: this script for client side ! jQuery