# Image input wont show in $_FILES

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to update an image in the my database. I have a modal that is loaded with jquery. When clicking on the save modification button, alla the form data shows up except for the image file, which does not show up in the $_FILES in php. I tried all the indication found on the web (php ini file enables file upload, images size is good). The code works if I use that classic submit method, but I don't want a full screen refresh, I need to do it all in ajax. Here is the html:

```js
        $('#updatePubDevFrm').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

 
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            alert(data);
            var url = '/PubDev/updatePubDev';
            $.post(url, data, null, 'json')
                    .done(function (data) {
                        if (data.status === "OK") {


                            $('#updatePubDevModal').removeClass('md-show');

                        } else {
                            alert("update error");
                        }
                    })
                    .fail(function (data) {
                        alert("ajax error");
                    })
                    .always(function () {

                    });



        });
```

```html
<div class="md-modal md-effect-1" id="updatePubDevModal" >
    <div class="md-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="md-close close">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Update Publisher/Developer</h4>
        </div>
        <form id="updatePubDevFrm" class="dz-clickable dropzone" action="/PubDev/updatePubDev" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row dropzone">
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pubDevName">System Id of Publisher/Developer</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Name of Publisher/Developer" name="pubDevIdDisplay" id="pubDevIdDisplay" class="form-control input-large" disabled="true">
                            <input type="hidden"  name="pubDevId" id="pubDevId" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pubDevName">Name of Publisher/Developer</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Name of Publisher/Developer" name="pubDevName-update" id="pubDevName-update" class="form-control input-large">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="date-founded">Date Founded</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Date founded" id="date-founded-update" name="date-founded-update" class="form-control date-picker input-large">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>What type of company is this?</label>
                            <div class="checkbox-nice">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="isPub-update" id="isPub-update">
                                <label for="date-founded-update">
                                    This company is a publisher
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox-nice">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="isDev-update" id="isDev-update">
                                <label for="isDev-update">
                                    This company is a developer
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <div class="main-box clearfix main-box-frame" >
                            <header class="main-box-header clearfix">
                                <h2>Upload Publisher /Developer Logo</h2>
                            </header>

                            <div class="main-box-body clearfix imgcontainer center">
                                <img id="preview" src="" class="pointable" alt="No Image Available" style="max-height:100%; max-width: 100%; "/>
                                <div class="main-box-body clearfix">
                                    <div id="dropzone" class="drop-zone-frame" >

                                        <input type="file" name="image2" id="image2">


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" id="confirmUpdPubdev" class="btn btn-primary">Save Modifications.</button>
            </div>
            
            
        </form>


    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the php code:

```
public function updatePubDev() {

    $fields = array();

    $fields[$this->pubdev->get_id_name()] = $this->input->post('pubDevId');
    $fields['name'] = $this->input->post('pubDevName-update');
    if ($this->input->post('date-founded'))
        $fields['date_founded'] = stampa_data_formato_DATE($this->input->post('date-founded-update'), '/');
    if ($this->input->post('isPub-update'))
        $fields['publisher'] = 1;
    else
        $fields['publisher'] = 0;

    if ($this->input->post('isDev-update'))
        $fields['developer'] = 1;
    else
        $fields['developer'] = 0;


    $row_count = $this->pubdev->update($fields,$this->pubdev->get_id_name());

    $file = $_FILES['image2'];

    //$idPubDev = $this->input->post("pubDevName");
    $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $path = dirname('../') . $ds . 'application' . $ds . 'assets' . $ds . 'img' . $ds . 'pub_devs' . $ds . 'logos' . $ds;
    //print_r($file);
    $info = new SplFileInfo($file['name']);
    //var_dump($info->getExtension());
    $filename = "logo_id_" . str_pad( $this->input->post('pubDevId'), 11, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "." . $info->getExtension();
    $result = $this->upload->uploadfile($file, $path, $filename);
    //echo "test";
    if ($result['status'] === "OK") {
        $logo = 'logo_id_' . str_pad($this->input->post('pubDevId'), 11, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . '.' . $info->getExtension();
        $this->pubdev->update(array('logo' => $logo, $this->pubdev->get_id_name() => $this->input->post('pubDevId')), $this->pubdev->get_id_name());
        $result['message'] = "file saved successfully";
        $result['query'] = $this->db->last_query();
    }

    $result['update_rows']= $row_count;
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

[image]

I tried the .ajax version, but the problem persist, here is the modified jquery:

```js
        $('#updatePubDevFrm').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();


            var data = $(this).serialize();

            var url = '/PubDev/updatePubDev';

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
            })

                    .done(function (data) {
                        if (data.status === "OK") {


                            $('#updatePubDevModal').removeClass('md-show');

                        } else {
                            alert("update error!");
                        }
                    })
                    .fail(function (data) {
                        alert("ajax error!");
                    })
                    .always(function () {

                    });



        });
```

It is not a duplicate question because the answer provide contained different properties necessary to uplaod both image and data inputs. these two properties in the $.ajax call are needed:

```
 processData: false,
  contentType: false
```

This way, it solved my problem.

Comment: Can you include `php` at Question?

Comment: I've inserted the php code as well (it's codeigniter)

Comment: everything before the  "$file = $_FILES['image2'];" instruction works. Everything after it isn't executed at all. This code works in a normal situation without jquery and ajax however.

Comment: Try substituting `$.ajax({type:"POST", processData:false, contentType:false})` for `$.post()`

Comment: In order to post files through jQuery you have to set `processData` option to false, `$.post` by itself does not set that, you have to use the second [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jQuery-post-settings) syntax and use a settings object

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399484/posting-file-input-as-filereader-binary-data-through-ajax-post

Comment: Please look at the jquery code again. I'm sorry, but I am working on this all day and I didn't realize that the jquery was the incorrect version. I reloaded the jquery code and took out the print_r command. The problems is still the same however.

Comment: I tried what you did but the problems persists

Comment: Use `FormData` as `data` instead of `$(this).serialize()`; e.g., `var data = new FormData(); data.append("file", $(":file", this)[0].files[0])`. You can alternatively use `file_get_contents("php://input")` as described at posted Answer

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36314992/

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Please put it as an answer so that I can award you the correct answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Salvo Which approach returned expected result? Using `FormData` or `file_get_contents("php://input")`, or both?

Comment: the first one, using the mdata object and then the $.ajax method setting the two parameters that you said

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Answer (score 1):

Use `FormData` as data instead of `$(this).serialize();`, set `processData` and `contentType` to `false`

```
   var data = new FormData();
   data.append("file", $(":file", this)[0].files[0]);
   $.ajax({
     url: "/PubDev/updatePubDev",
     type: "POST",
     data: data,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `file_get_contents('php://input');` to get the upload content.